# Can't use Store with Template in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following model:

```
Ext.define('RateManagement.model.Service', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
    ]
});
```

And, I have the following Store:

```
Ext.define("RateManagement.store.ServiceStore", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'RateManagement.model.Service',
    autoLoad: true,
    data: [
        {
            name: 'Test Service'
        }
    ]
});
```

I then create a template like this:

```
var tpl2 = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<a href="#">{name}</a>'
).compile();
```

And, I finally try to use the Store and the Template in my Window like so:

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
    el:'hello-win',
    //layout:'fit',
    width:500,
    title: 'View All Services',
    height:300,
    closeAction:'hide',
    plain: true,

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            enableKeyEvents: true,
            listeners: {
                keyup: function(c) {
                    console.log(c.getValue());                       
                }
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            //title: 'test',
            preventHeader: true,
            height: 100,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            tpl: tpl2,
            store: RateManagement.store.ServiceStore
            //data: data
        }
    ],

    buttons: [{
        text:'Submit',
        disabled:true
    },{
        text: 'Close',
        handler: function(){
            win.hide();
        }
    }]
});
```

However, the "Test Service" link never appears in my window and there are no errors in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

**Edit:**  Updated with the latest code.

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        listeners: {
            keyup: function(c) {
                console.log(c.getValue());                       
            }
        }
    },
    {
        xtype: 'dataview',
        itemSelector: 'a.serviceLink',
        tpl: tpl2,
        store: RateManagement.store.ServiceStore
        //data: data
    }
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `XTemplate` works fine ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/89cHE/)), but you are not passing any [`data`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-data) to it in your panel.

The [`tpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-tpl) is used in conjunction with the [`data`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-data) configurations.

### Edit:

You need to use an instance of a store.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/k4ggq/

Comment: How do I use `data` with my `store`?  My data is in my store.

Comment: why aren't you using a `dataView`?

Comment: :) because I am new and don't know what I'm doing!  I am simply trying to have data in a store and then display it via a template.

Comment: So have a look at `dataView` - it uses an `Ext.XTemplate` as its internal templating mechanism, and is bound to an `Ext.data.Store` so that as the data in the store changes the view is automatically updated to reflect the changes.

Comment: I found this but I am not sure how to apply it.  Would it be possible for a quick example?  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/view/data-view.html

Comment: Have a look at the [example in the docs](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.View)

Comment: No I mean I don't know how to apply it to my items like `xtype: 'view.View',` or `xtype: 'view'`; both don't work.  How can I integrate it into what I have now, please?

Comment: use: `xtype: 'dataview'`

Comment: Thanks, but the errors I am now getting in console is `Ext.data.Store created with no model.` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getProxy' of undefined `

Comment: you are not creating an instance of the store, here is a example: http://jsfiddle.net/k4ggq/